# vertical jquery accordion that will fill empty percentage when siblings collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Trying to get a jQuery vertical accordion working with 3 separate panels, A, B and C, each currently 33.3% wide. What I am trying to accomplish is when you collapse A, B & C will fill up the other 33% of that new available space from A being collapsed. If you close A & B then C would fill up 100% of the empty space. Any help is much appreciated as I am sure I may be approaching this the complete wrong way?

http://jsfiddle.net/Mvr3P/

HTML

```
<div id="toggle"><div id="toggle-button"></div></div>
<div id="toggle2"><div id="toggle-button2"></div></div>
<div id="toggle3"><div id="toggle-button3"></div></div>
```

CSS

```
#toggle {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width:33.3%;
    background:red;
}

#toggle2 {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width:33.3%;
    background:blue;
}

#toggle3 {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width:33.3%;
    background:green;
}

#toggle-button {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background:blue;
}

#toggle-button2 {
    height:20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: purple;
}

#toggle-button3 {
    height:20px;
    width: 100%;
    background:orange;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $('#toggle-button').click( function() {

        var toggleWidth = $("#toggle").width();

        if (toggleWidth = "33.3%") {
            toggleWidth ="100%";
        }

        else if (toggleWidth = "100%") {
          toggleWidth = "10px";
        }

        else {
          toggleWidth = "33.3%"
        }

        $('#toggle').animate({ width: toggleWidth });

  });

  $('#toggle-button2').click( function() {

    var toggleWidth = $("#toggle2").width();

    if (toggleWidth = "33.3%") {
        toggleWidth ="100%";
    }

    else if (toggleWidth = "100%") {
      toggleWidth = "10px";
    }

    else {
      toggleWidth = "33.3%"
    }

    $('#toggle2').animate({ width: toggleWidth });

});

$('#toggle-button3').click( function() {

    var toggleWidth = $("#toggle3").width();

    if (toggleWidth = "33.3%") {
        toggleWidth ="100%";
    }

    else if (toggleWidth = "100%") {
      toggleWidth = "10px";
    }

    else {
      toggleWidth = "33.3%"
    }

    $('#toggle3').animate({ width: toggleWidth });

    });
});
```

Comment: You could do this easily with CSS [`display: table-cell`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/), although [animating them would require some trickery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2380968).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mvr3P/3/ Something like this? 
(Sorry if not - i just "gulped" some beer) :P
It's hard to understand what are You willing to achieve :) Maybe some screens??:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a few tricky things going on here - the biggest challenge being how to animate more than one thing at a time.

JSFiddle of the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/vYzpB/1/

Firstly, using classes to generically label your elements will allow you to write less code. This is a hugely important thing especially when you're applying the same behavior to more than one element. As you seem to know, you should only have one ID, but you can have many elements with the same class name.

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div id="toggle" class="toggle-item"><div id="toggle-button" class="toggle-button"></div></div>
    <div id="toggle2" class="toggle-item"><div id="toggle-button2" class="toggle-button"></div></div>
    <div id="toggle3" class="toggle-item expanded"><div id="toggle-button3" class="toggle-button"></div></div>
</div>
```

Additionally, wrap all of the elements in a parent div (which I called `accordion`). I'll explain why shortly.

With that change, we can apply a click event to the `.toggle-button` class that handles the event for each of the accordion items:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.toggle-button').click( function() {
        // capture the parent div with the class of 'toggle-item'
        var $parentToggle = $(this).parent('.toggle-item');

        // run this within setTimeout so that both animations
        // run at the same time. This is called "running asynchronously"
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('.toggle-item').not($parentToggle).animate({
                width: '10%'
            });
        }, 0);

        $parentToggle.animate({
            width: '80%'
        });

    });
});
```

The `window.setTimeout` is the secret sauce here. Without it, jQuery will wait until the first animation is finished, THEN move on to the next. By wrapping the first animation inside a `setTimeout` we essentially remove it from the top-to-bottom execution process and call it **asynchronously**. We set this to timeout at "0" because we actually want it to run right away (as opposed to waiting a certain amount of milliseconds).

**The CSS**

The CSS has a "default state" `.expanded` class we add to the element intended to take up the 2/3 (or whatever % you want) space.

Notice also how that new parent div has a set width. Without it, the elements will flop around while transitioning.

```
.accordion {
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.toggle-item {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 10%;
}

.expanded {
    width: 80%;
}

#toggle {
    background:red;
}

#toggle2 {
    background:blue;
}

#toggle3 {
    background:green;
}

.toggle-button {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;  
}

#toggle-button {
    background:blue;
}

#toggle-button2 {
    background: purple;
}

#toggle-button3 {
    background:orange;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed help on that, very much appreciated! Question, so is it possible then to allow two of the panels to take up 100% or close to 100% when one panel is collapsed? I'm essentially trying to give the user the ability to collapse one or two of the panels and the remaining panels fills 100%, also allowing them to have all 3 panels open at once if they want the complete view?

Comment: In that case, just change the values of the widths in the animation/css. You can also capture the width of any element and do the math against the parent div, by using `$('.my-target-class').width();` (also, please mark my answer as "answered" if it helped. Thanks!)